# Extract links from an html page using xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract the links on this html page:

```
<div class="listbox">
      <div class="mainbox" onclick="www.abc.com">
```

I've tried using:

```
//div[@class="listbox"]/a/text()
//div/onclick/text()
```

but they return an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can obtain the link via using Selenium and the `getAttribute` method.
First find the element (or elements and then loop) that have the links inside their onclick attributes, then just get them via getAttribute:

## Selenium + Java:

```
String link = driver.findElement(By.className("mainbox")).getAttribute("onclick");
```

## Selenium + Python:

I'm no python guy, but it should work like this:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_class_name("mainbox")).get_attribute("onclick");
```

Comment: I'm using python, it gives back invalid syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Such XPath must work for you.

```
/div/div/@onclick
```

or more precise

```
/div[@class="listbox"]/div[@class="mainbox"]/@onclick
```